# Return types of SQL query were not specified (Int16)

Tags: sql, nhibernate, stored-procedures

I am calling TSQL stored procedure from NHibernate 1.2.

```
var q = sessionStrategyNHibernate.GetSession()
   .CreateSQLQuery("exec myProc ?, ?, ?, ?")
   .SetString(0, "77")
   .SetInt32(1, 1)
   .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(Int16)))
   .SetParameter(2, dateMinInclue, NHibernateUtil.DateTime)
   .SetParameter(3, dateMaxExclue, NHibernateUtil.DateTime);

var nb = q.UniqueResult<Int16>();
```

The stored procedure `myProc` returns a int (count)

```
create procedure myProc 
(
    @A nvarchar(255), 
    @B int,
    @C datetime,
    @D datetime
)
as
begin

    select count(*) as NB
    from ...

end
go
```

But an error is thrown each time

```
Message : Return types of SQL query were not specified [exec myProc ?, ?, ?, ?]
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

COUNT returns SQL Server `int` which is signed 32 bit. Not `Int16`

Comment: Same error. But it's not surprising as error message says "not specified".